# Assigning text box "other" value to radio button value

Tags: javascript, html

I've spent over three hours on this trying to work with the code I've been given. I've never done javascript. Please help.
I have a form with 4 radio buttons, one specifying "other" and next to a text box that is supposed to post the user specified value. Here's what I've tried.
HTML:

```
<td id="amount_container">
    <input name="chargetotal" type="radio" value="75.00" onclick="donation_value();" />$75<br />
    <input name="chargetotal" type="radio" value="125.00" onclick="donation_value();" />$125<br />
    <input name="chargetotal" type="radio" value="250.00" onclick="donation_value();" />$250<br />
    <input name="chargetotal" type="radio" value="other" />other
    <input type="text" name="specified" size="10" />
</td>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function donation_value(){
    var val = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < document.form1.chargetotal.length; i++ ) {
        if( document.form1.chargetotal[i].checked == true ) {
            val = document.form1.chargetotal[i].value;
            if(val=='other') {
                document.form1.specified.disabled=false;
                document.form1.specified.focus();
                document.form1.chargetotal.value=document.form1.specified.value;
            } else {
                document.form1.specified.disabled=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, you forgot to add onclick handler to "other" radio. 
I think it should be

```
<input name="chargetotal" type="radio" value="other" onclick="donation_value();"/>
```

**Update**

I think I understood what your problem is :)
You can add callback, whick will be invoked when page is submitted. This callback will set value for "other" radio if it is selected. Something like

```
function assignOtherValue() {
    for( i = 0; i < document.form1.chargetotal.length; i++ ) {
        if( document.form1.chargetotal[i].checked == true ) {
            var val = document.form1.chargetotal[i].value;
            if(val=='other') {
                document.form1.chargetotal[i].value=document.form1.specified.value;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And add to form:

```
<form name="form1" onSubmit="return assignOtherValue();">
```

Comment: You're right. I had it in before and took it out and I thought it still "worked". But the value in the check box does not get assigned to "chargetotal" when the page is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your js:

```
function donation_value(){
    var val = 0;
    var the_form = document.forms['form1'];
    for( i = 0; i < the_form.chargetotal.length; i++ ) {
        if( the_form.chargetotal[i].checked == true ) {
            val = the_form.chargetotal[i].value;
            if(val=='other') {
                the_form.specified.disabled=false;
                the_form.specified.focus();
                the_form.chargetotal.value=the_form.specified.value;
            } else {
                the_form.specified.disabled=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/vQNyY/

Comment: Same results only the focusing doesn't work anymore. By using the line document.form1.chargetotal.value=document.form1.specified.value; That line is forcing it and doesn't work. Everything else focuses on what should be the right value. But the text box doesn't post as "chargetotal" and I don't know how to assign it.